# jQuery Ajax each function check return ID is the same as the previous one

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, loops, each

I am using AJAX to grab data from a remove server , then I am using each to loop.

Now what I want to do is if the return value data is the same as the previous one I do something
I have 10 val.userId == 1 , I wanna to do sth in once only not in 10 times.

how about in the real case I do not know the user ID i wanna make it dynamic
fox example user 12123  has 10 times ,  user 1239823 has 1000 times

FOr example here 
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        getData();
      });


function getData(){
    $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(response){

              $.each(response, function(index, val) {
                console.log(val); // get all return data
                // as we can see userId == 1 have 10 posts , I just want to console.log only once if usdId == 1
                if(val.userId == 1){
                  console.log(val.userId);  // this one consoloe .log 10 times since we have 10 userId 
                }
                // how about in the real case I do not know the user ID i wanna make it dynamic
                // fox example user 12123  has 10 times ,  user 1239823 has 1000 times 

              });


          },
          error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){console.log(xhr.statusText);console.log(textStatus);console.log(error);

          }
    });
  }
```

thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove duplicate items based on `userId`, you can make a loop with the response and filter them.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    getData();
});


function getData(){
    $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(response){
              var arr = [];
              
              response.forEach(function (item) {
                var result = arr.find(x => x.userId === item.userId);
                if (!result) {
                  arr.push(item);
                }
              });
              
              console.log(arr);
          },
          error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){            
              console.log(xhr.statusText);
              console.log(textStatus);
              console.log(error);
          }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```